# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] when reading Website into Pandas

Tags: python, error-handling, connection

I try to read the website "https://www.zacks.com/earnings/earnings-calendar" into Pandas with the code below, but I always get the following error: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.zacks.com/earnings/earnings-calendar', header = 1)
```

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Did you solve this? I am getting the same error.

Comment: no i didnt solve it